# Delete records with same ID if one record has an invalid value

Tags: sql-server

I have table with 307807 rows in SQL. I want to delete records if my start_date and end_date columns have invalid values. Unfortunately my userID is repeated more than once. Therefore I want to delete userID's that were affected by invalid values.

```
UserID ---- start_date ---- end_date
123    ---- 06-05-1934 ---- 16-05-1934
123    ---- 06-05-1933 ---- 16-05-1933
123    ---- /N         ---- 16-03-1920
234    ---- 04-03-1945 ---- 17-04-1945
234    ---- 05-06-1999 ---- 06-07-1999
```

Here I want to delete all records with userID 123, as I cannot work with that data anymore.

I use MS SQL Server Management Studio 17.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to select all users with a bad date and then delete records for those users:

```
WITH BadUsers as (
SELECT DISTINCT UserID from TableA 
where start_date = '/n' or end_date ='n'
)
DELETE FROM TableA
JOIN BadUsers ON
Table.UserID = BadUser.UserID
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I did this in two steps, but solved my problem!

Answer (score 1):

use `TRY_CONVERT` to check if the `datetime` is valid

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT indictr = Min(CASE WHEN Try_convert(datetime, start_date, 105) IS NULL OR Try_convert(datetime, end_date, 105) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)
                            OVER(partition BY UserID ),*
         FROM   Yourtable)
DELETE FROM cte
WHERE  indictr = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[TRY_CAST (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-cast-transact-sql#syntax)** as:

```
CREATE TABLE T (
    ID INT,
    SDate VARCHAR(10),
    EDate VARCHAR(10)
    );

INSERT INTO T VALUES
(123, '1934-05-06', '1634-05-16'),
(123, '/N', '1934-05-25'),
(123, '1934-05-26', 'WrongDate');

SELECT *
FROM T;

DELETE FROM T
WHERE ID IN 
        (
         SELECT DISTINCT ID 
         WHERE (TRY_CAST(SDate AS DATE) IS NULL) OR (TRY_CAST(EDate AS DATE) IS NULL) 
        );

SELECT *
FROM T;
```